# How does rebooting a computer with a keyboard driver work?

Tags: assembly, x86, keyboard, kernel, driver

I'm just learning kernel programming from this tutorial, which is in Polish - https://pl.wikibooks.org/wiki/Pisanie_OS
It says there that the keyboard driver have many uses including rebooting the computer. It's a code for that:

```
reset: 
     call kbd 
     mov al,0xfe 
     out 0x64,al 

kbd0:   
     jmp short $+2 
     in al,60h 
kbd:    jmp short $+2 
     in al,64h 
     test al,1 
     jnz kbd0 
     test al,2 
     jnz kbd 
     ret
```

I don't understand this code. Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: The code that actually sends a reset command to the keyboard controller are the 2 instructions  `mov al,0xfe` `out 0x64,al` writes command 0xfe to the keyboard controller. 0xfe is the reset command. The rest of the code that gets called first effectively ensures that the keyboard controller buffer with data the keyboard has sent to the PC is empty. If it isn't is reads the data that is present and then does the same check again until the buffer is empty.

Comment: Then it checks to see if the send buffer is full (before you send a command you make sure send buffer is empty). If it is the entire process is done over again. Once it finds that both the send buffer and receive buffer are both empty then the function `kbd` returns at which point the reset command is sent.

Comment: As for the `jmp short $+2` Those are the same as jumping to the instruction after the JMP. It will only create a small delay before accessing the ports. I don't believe they are necessary even on old hardware.

Comment: I personally believe the code is doing stuff it doesn't have to. When sending a command to the keyboard controller (like 0xfe to reset the system) it should only be necessary to ensure the send buffer (input buffer from the perspective of the 8042 chip) is empty before sending a command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 8086 processer has a reset pin.  When asserted, this resets the processor to its initial state.  This pin is connected to the keyboard controller; if you ask the keyboard controller to pull the reset pin up and then back down (which is what the code you posted does), the processor is reset.

Modern x86 processors work a bit different from that and the keyboard controller is no longer a separate chip.  But still, the same method causes the southbridge to generate a reset signal, rebooting the computer.

Comment: @RomanKwaśniewski: It isn't, but when the IBM PC/AT hardware came out there wasn't all the info (that we now know). The hardware manufacturers (IBM) devised the reset via the keyboard controller method. It wasn't until later on when OS/2 1.x came around that someone figured out that if you could generate a triple fault that you would get a guaranteed CPU reset. The keyboard method was slower and someone was looking for a faster way. I believe OS/2 for the 286 ended up invalidating the entire Interrupt Descriptor Table and then causing an exception. This would cause a triple fault.

Comment: @RomanKwaśniewski : The keyboard reset method to reset works in all modes (real and 16-bit protected mode) so it was useful to reset from real mode as well. Triple faults could only occur in protected mode. This was in a time before Advanced Power Management (APM) services where you could do a reset that way.

Comment: @MichaelPetch The 8086 doesn't have the concept of a triple fault.  On the 80286, the triple fault mechanism was documented in the instruction set reference.

Comment: @fuz: I never said anything about the 8086. I said the *80286*. And for the record, the IBM-PC didn't use the 8042 controller. The 8042 and the reset mechanism were new to the IBM PC/AT (80286) - which your answer incorrectly suggests. IBM developed the 8042 CPU reset mechanism to overcome the shortcoming identified when trying to get out of protected mode on the 80286 back to real mode.

Comment: It should be noted that IBM was notorious for not reading everything in the Intel processor specs. We wouldn't have had IBM putting IRQ0 to IRQ7 on interrupt vector 8 through 15 in the reserved space that Intel documented. And it is true that the method to guarantee a reset on a triple fault wasn't identified until OS/2 developers wanted a faster mechanism. It was at that point someone realized they could use the triple fault on the 80286 to get the same desired behaviour and be done faster. It was the excessive port overhead of accessing the 8042 that the OS/2 devs wanted to speed up.

Comment: I can't speak to what the IBM development team knew or didn't know. But the reality is that prior to the IBM-PC/AT there was no 8042 controller used, nor was there a keyboard reset mechanism on the original IBM-PC's (through the PPI). The IBM-PC/AT was developed w/8042 and they shunted the A20 and the reset line through it. The reset was specifically because they thought they needed a way out of protected mode with a reset. They divised that mechanism. It wasn't until OS/2 dev where someone realized that a triple fault would serve the same purpose.

Comment: The only thing I can think is that you may be confused with the fact that Control-Alt-Delete on the IBM-PC restarted the computer? Control-Alt-Delete was not a physical hardware solution on the IBM computers. The check for Control-Alt-Del was a feature put into the BIOS keyboard handler. It checked for that control sequence and then made a jump to the BIOS reset vector. Because it was a BIOS/software solution (and not something external) it wasn't always reliable depending how software ended up screwing up the normal operation of the PC.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I'm pretty sure the original IBM PC too had a keyboard controller which managed the reset line.  What was new in the AT was that the A20 gate was also managed by the keyboard controller.  My comment about triple faults on the 8086 resulted from me misreading your comments.  Sorry for that.

Comment: @fuz, The IBM-PC/XT variants before the AT used an 8255 (PPI) on ports 0x60 (data) and 0x61 (control) for keyboard. There were no bit for reset nor could you send a reset command to the keyboard controller. With the advent of the IBM-PC/AT(80286) they moved to using an 8042 controller. They then added a 0xfe command  that the keyboard controller understood. They also shunted the A20 line through the controller as well. Port 0x64 that you can send commands to the keyboard controller didn't exist on the IBM-PC via the 8255.

Comment: The 8255's reset input pin was tied to the reset line of the system so that when a reset did occur,  all the ports on the 8255 went back to a default input state.